# How can a make a button that hides text,so text remains hidden until a person presses the button?

Tags: text, button

so this is the type of thing I'm trying to do:

[image: Button that when clicked display hidden text]

When I click on this button,it displays a hidden text:

[image]

Comment: see the examples in [OpenerView](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenerView.html) and [PaneSelector]http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PaneSelector.html